# How do I connect to an .mdf (Microsoft SQL Server Database File) in a simple web project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio-2008

Specifically, in VS 2008, I want to connect to a data source that you can have by right-clicking on the automatically-generated App_Data folder (an .mdf "database"). Seems easy, and it is once you know how.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So here's the answer from MSDN:

> Choos[e] "Add New Data Source" from the
>   Data menu.[And follow the connection wizard]

Very easy, except that I have no Data menu. If you don't have a Data menu, do the following:

- Click on Tools >> Connect to Database...
- Select "Microsoft SQL Server Database File", take the default Data provider, and click OK
- On the next screen, browse to your Database file, which will be in your VS Solution folder structure somewhere.

Test the connection. It'll be good. If you want to add the string to the web.config, click the Advanced button, and copy the Data Source line (at the bottom of the dialog box), and paste it into a connection string in the appropriate place in the web.config file. You will have to add the "`AttachDbFilename`" attribute and value. Example:

The raw text from the Advanced panel:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```

The actual entry in the web.config:

```
<add name="SomeDataBase" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; 
AttachDbFilename=C:\Development\blahBlah\App_Data\SomeDataFile.mdf;
Integrated Security=True; Connect Timeout=30; User Instance=True" />
```

Answer (score 20):

A great resource I always keep around is [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com).
It's really handy for finding these connection strings when you can't find an example.

Particularly [this page](http://connectionstrings.com/?carrier=sqlserver2005) applied to your problem

**Attach a database file on connect to a local SQL Server Express instance**

```
Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=c:\asd\qwe\mydbfile.mdf; Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just one more -- i've always kept a udl file on my desktop to easily create and test connection strings. If you've never done it before - create a new text file and name it to connection.udl (the ext is the only important part).  Open the file, start on the Provider tab and work your way through. Once you're happy with the connection rename the file giving it a .txt extension. Open the file and copy the string - it's relatively easy and lets you test the connection before using it.

Comment: Nice; one note would be that the file should be completely empty.  I initially added a space to make it dirty, so that Notepad++ would save it, and this fails.

Answer (score 3):

```
<add name="Your Database" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Expanse.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Login.aspx.cs (the code behind file for your login page in the submit button click event) add

```
string constr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\myData.mdf; Integrated Security=True; Connect Timeout=30;";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
string constr =    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myData"].ToString();

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
sqlQuery=" Your Query here"
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
com.Connection.Open();
string strOutput = (string)com.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: This needs some editing. Some lines and variables are repeated.