# How to update / delete ASPNETDB.MDF 'vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers'?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to update / delete ASPNETDB.MDF 'vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers'

To enable / disable the site registers users or delete users ///

using asp.net

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking.  Do you want to know how to update the view or how to add the ability to enable/disable/delete users from a site?

Comment: I want to know how to Update / delete the table records in ASPNETDB.MDF in single update / delete query ?

Answer (score 0):

for Deleting you can use:

```
using System.Web.Security;

Membership.DeleteUser(TextBox_username.Text);
```

and for updating a username you can use above cod .first delete it and then make a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can't explicitly delete rows from a view (vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers), but this view is most likely based on the AspNetUsers table.

1. Connect to the MDF file (which is probably in your App_Data folder) in Visual Studio:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/173221/188926
2. Right-click the database in Server Explorer > New Query
3. type: `delete from AspNetUsers` and hit run (you may need to delete from AspNetRoles first)