# How do I connect to an MDF database file?

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2010

I'm experimenting in connecting a C# app to an MDF database for the first time, and I need a little help ..

I made a small MDF database file in Visual Studio 2010, then created another project and imported the file into the project itself.

I am not trying to connect to the MDF file via code. Here the code I'm using:

```
namespace DBtestApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "DataSource=.\\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename =SampleDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
            con.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connection opened");
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Connection closed");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the application, I get an exception at the line where I define the connection string, and the exception has this message at the top of the stack:

```
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'datasource'.
```

Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: this post might help:

[How do I connect to an .mdf (Microsoft SQL Server Database File) in a simple web project?][1]

Cheerz

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173209/how-do-i-connect-to-an-mdf-microsoft-sql-server-database-file-in-a-simple-web

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Add space between `Data Source`

```
 con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                          AttachDbFilename=c:\folder\SampleDatabase.mdf;
                          Integrated Security=True;
                          Connect Timeout=30;
                          User Instance=True";
```

Comment: And while you're editing, remove the spaces in `; AttachDbFilename =`

Comment: Tried it, but now I got the following exception: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file SampleDatabase.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.`

Comment: You need to specify the path of sampleDatabase.mdf. Have a look at edited post.

Comment: But why should I specify the complete path when I've added the MDF file to the project's local resources ? .. I don't want to hardcode a path as that would mean that MDF file always has to be there .. Can I not reference to its local presence within the project ?

Comment: Use AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SampleDatabase.mdf instead of absolute path.

Comment: Alright, it worked, thanks ! This is the final line I used: `con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SampleDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";`

Comment: I was thinking of editing this so that the string was concatenated to eliminate the horizontal scroll, but I'm afraid I don't know enough about this to trust myself not to make the answer incorrect.

Answer (score 26):

Go to server explorer > Your Database > Right Click > properties > ConnectionString and copy the connection string and past the copied to connectiongstring code :)

Comment: One of the best answers I've seen so far :)

Comment: This will break the moment you try it on another machine. While that connection string is valid for your machine, if you take a moment to read it you'll notice that it has the path hardcoded.

Answer (score 10):

```
string sqlCon = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                @"AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SampleDB.mdf;
                Integrated Security=True;
                Connect Timeout=30;
                User Instance=True";
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(sqlCon);
```

The filepath should have **|DataDirectory|** which actually links to "current project directory\App_Data\" or "current project directory" and get the .mdf file.....Place the .mdf in either of these places and should work in visual studio 2010.And when you use the standalone application on production system, then the current path where the executable file is, should have the .mdf file.

Answer (score 8):

For Visual Studio 2015 the connection string is:

```
"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me with an MDF. I'm using VS2019 with .Net Core 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=c:\mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Comment: I tried this modified version" `"Server=.\\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=SampleDatabase.mdf;Database=SampleDatabase; Trusted_Connection=Yes"`, and got the following exception: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A file activation error occurred. The physical file name 'SampleDatabase.mdf' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.
Cannot attach the file 'SampleDatabase.mdf' as database 'SampleDatabase'.`

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution, where you can have the database in the folder you want inside the solution. That worked for me:

```
.ConnectionString(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;
                    AttachDbFilename="+AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"Folder1\\Folder2\\SampleDatabase.mdf" + ";
                    Integrated Security=True;")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Samples\MyApp\C#\bin\Debug\Login.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
```

this is working for me... Is there any way to short the path? like

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=\bin\Debug\Login.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\hasif\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\vgsoft\SqlserverRepo\data\Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

### 1

[image]

### 2

[image]

### ConnectionString

[image]