# How to create the program after finished programming it in C#

Tags: c#, portability, portable-applications

So I've finished programming my project in C# and now I want to make it into a program that can run without Visual Studio. How do I do that?

I want the executable and all that so I can put my program on a flash drive and give to my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the configuration to Debug or Release, then click Build -> Build {name} Solution or Build -> Build {name} project. Under the source folder there will be a bin\Debug and bin\Release folder with your executable in. Visual Studio will build it as you are running it in the IDE anyway so this step isn't strictly necessary but best to make sure its the latest build.

Your friend needs to have the .net framework installed to be able to run your app. This needs to match the version that you built your app with. He can browse to http://smallestdotnet.com to check what version he has installed.

Answer (score 4):

There are a view possibilities here.

1. Copy the content of the bin\debug or the bin\release folder in
   your project folder.
2. Publish the application as an offline one-click application (this one will install it.)
3. Create an installer project manually
4. Use WIX to create an installer project
5. Create your own installer application.

Developpers deployment strategies => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965.aspx

Comment: Ok, so i used the publish wizard but it didn't keep the populated database after it was published? is there any way to keep the populated database in the setup? when it's published

Comment: Depends on what database you are using? In the publishing wizard you can always specify a file that needs to be executed after the installation, that file can than be an sql generate script. But understand a database is loosely coupled (as it is supposed to be) from your application, so it's logical that the installer doesn't do changes to it, without you explicitly specifying what those changes must be.

Comment: i imported the ms sql database from an excel file  then from the sql i used a data source to connect the c# program and the sql. its more or less 3000 rows of data. after the import there is no script. it was all generated by the importing program. all i can see is a .ldf and .mdf file for the database

Comment: Since it's an .mdf file, you can include it in your project and set the output to copy always. (in the properties tab when you click on the mdf file).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926512/how-do-i-connect-to-an-mdf-database-file
This might help for the connection, this way the person you are giving it to only needs to have sqlexpress installed (which nowadays most pc already have by default.)

Comment: im still having problems. please can you join me on my teamspeak server just so i can talk to you for a minute. would really appreciate it. IP : cogclan.no-ip.biz

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49729/discussion-between-woutervs-and-andrea-visnenza-andy)

Answer (score 1):

what i usualy do is go to file and press "Save as" then copy the file location and paste it
somewhere else. Then go to your bin>debug and it should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Ususaly you can find it in your Bin folder under Debug or Release.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build it, under Build menu. Then the executable will be located in your project's bin folder either in Debug or Release folders.

Answer (score 0):

Click On Build-> Build Solution, It will build solution , go in bin/debug folder in your project folder and find executable. Also you can build one click installer, Click on  build-> publish 'project name' . Complete wizard , it will create installer and install it.