# Error when running my app on another machine

Tags: c#, vb.net

I almost finished my program, it runs fine on my computer. However when I try it on virtual machine (Win7) I'm getting error, Here's a screenshot:

**UPDATE 2:**

[image: Screenshot]

**UPDATE 1:** Here's full error output:
https://gist.github.com/nikel/1356be52475e4515707638ed97402790

And this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I defined attachdbfilename like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.DataSource = @"(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB";
    builder.AttachDBFilename = @"|DataDirectory|\database\gazi_db.mdf";
    builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    builder.ConnectTimeout = 30;
    sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
    ...
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have a localDb\MSSQLLocalDB set up in the virtual machine? and that mdf file?

Comment: Yes, I tried installing several sql servers (if you mean that) and mdf files are present in same directory as exe.

Comment: How did you go with this problem abi?

Comment: not so good. I'm waiting for a solution.

Comment: I give up installing / uninstalling sql versions

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the correct answer is but I imagine the problem is your virtual machine does not have some dependency that your application expects.

Please take a look at [How do I connect to an MDF database file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926512/how-do-i-connect-to-an-mdf-database-file)

Do you have SQL Server Express on your Windows 7 virtual machine?

Comment: hmm let me try installing sql server again

Comment: Can you try to upload your error output again? https://gist.github.com/nikel/7cf254...aed24d9ee43483 leads to 404 because it looks like there is a `...` in the URL

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the question. Just tried installing localdb sql but still the same.