# C# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification error

Tags: c#

I hava a C# code that throwing an error:

```
SqlConnection sq = new SqlConnection(@"C:\USERS\USER\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2012\PROJECTS\LOGINAPP\DB\LOGINDB.MDF");
            string q = "Select * from Table where textBox1= '" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "'and Password'" + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter s = new SqlDataAdapter(q, sq);
            DataTable d = new DataTable();
            s.Fill(d);
            if (d.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                frmMain G = new frmMain();
                this.Hide();
                G.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Check your Username or Password or both");
            }
```

this code throwing (Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification) error, so how can i fix it?
[image]

Comment: i made a simple database here

Comment: Pro tip: post error messages as *text*, not images. Everything in that message box can be copied and pasted with Ctrl+C. And if you drop down the "Details", you can show us the stack trace, too.

Comment: See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

Comment: What is the error near Keyword Table ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SqlConnection` requires a connection string, not a path to a file. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926512/how-do-i-connect-to-an-mdf-database-file) and [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx).