# Locate database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have used SQL Server Management Studio to convert an Access file to SQL Server. I want to add this database to a project using C# (it appears in Server Explorer - Data Connections).

When I use C#, Solution Explorer - Properties - AddResource - Add Existing file I am required to navigate to the database file, but I cannot locate it.

Database is RWJ-PC.PaulsNewDatabase.dbo. Please advise if possible.

Comment: How have you used SSMS to convert an Access file to SQL Server?  I didn't know such a thing was possible.  Did you import data?

Comment: Data was imported. I have description of how but too long to add to comments. How can I forward ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C:\ProgramFiles\MicrosoftSQLServer\MSSQL12.MSSQLServer\MSSQL\Data\Filename

Found eventually by trolling the internet

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere on your hard disk (or in a network folder)is a file with an extension of mdf. Attach the file to your SQL Server (using SQL Server Management Studio) instance and you will have a a database. SQL Server databases live on the file system as a mdf and (possible one or more ndf) file(s). It lives in memory and can be used when attached to a SQL Server instance.

Comment: DataBase should be on a local drive on same PC as Server.

Answer (score -1):

If you have imported the data into an instance of SQL server you can connect to the instance of SQL or to the mdf.  Look here --

[How do I connect to an MDF database file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926512/how-do-i-connect-to-an-mdf-database-file)

Search for connecting to SQL Server with C# (VB.Net).  You can use Entity Frame work or connect directly.