# I want to create a connection string with .mdf file in window forms application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

This is my connection string:

```
<add name="EntityContext" 
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS; 
                       AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\PasLockProduction.mdf;
                       Database=PasLockProduction;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: Why - do you get an error? If so: **what** error??

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)'

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples, sample data or error messages into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: You're connection to a `.\SQLEXPRESS` instance - are you **sure** you have installed SQL Server **Express** with that default instance name??

Comment: When you run `SELECT @@VERSION` against your SQL Server instance - what output do you get?

Comment: If you use the command prompt and do this what happens? `sqlcmd -S .\sqlexpress` . Are you sure you have it installed and you're not confusing it with LocalDB?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) 
 Feb 20 2014 20:04:26 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 16299: )
@marc_s

Comment: You have installed a **Standard** edition of SQL Server - but that feature of using `AttachDbFileName=.....` is available ***only*** with SQL Server **Express** edition

Comment: ohhh i see..now what i do ?? any other solution ??

Comment: i want  just run my application with data base on client machine..my database created in sqlserver..any other way to do it ?

Comment: you need LocalDB installed if you want to use an MDF file without installing SQL Server. Search for LocalDB in google there is plenty to find there

Answer (score 0):

Try someting like this.

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EntityContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=c:\folder\PasLockProduction.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: but i want to use mdf file no data base

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926512/how-do-i-connect-to-an-mdf-database-file

Comment: dint find any thing related my question

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `DataDirectory` is not what you think it is. In the Interactive window or even in your code where you can set a breakpoint do this to see where that directory is:

```
var ddir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory");
```

To set the directory to where your database file is :

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", "<path to file...");
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is the file not being found - the error says *The server was not found.....*

Comment: Yup  i agree.but why server not found

Comment: @marc_s yeah, I see.