# System.ArgumentException: 'Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mysql-connector

I have a problem with the SqlConnection, the display can't open in Visual Studio

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"D:\APLIKASI ALPEM\BISMILLAH\WINDOWSFORMSAPP1\LOGIN.MDF");
```

Comment: how did you get this string `D:\APLIKASI ALPEM\BISMILLAH\WINDOWSFORMSAPP1\LOGIN.MDF`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I connect to an MDF database file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926512/how-do-i-connect-to-an-mdf-database-file)

Answer (score 0):

Your path to database file contains space, so should be taken with double quotes at the beginning and the end.
Try this:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "DataSource=.\\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=\"D:\\APLIKASI ALPEM\\BISMILLAH\\WINDOWSFORMSAPP1\\LOGIN.MDF\";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
```