# How to change SQL connection strings data source?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I'm beginner in C# and SQL Server.  Currently I’m developing a program, the problem is my database file is in DB folder inside project folder.  When I try to detach the database file in SQL Server Management Studio it gives an error:

```
"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=true"
```

When I the change data source to this

```
"Data Source=db/test.mdf;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=true"
```

it gives an error.  I don’t know how to insert database file with project to InstallShield to create setup file.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173209/how-do-i-connect-to-an-mdf-microsoft-sql-server-database-file-in-a-simple-web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set up connection using DATA-> new data source dialog. There you will set up all the parameters visually. I think the problem here is that full path is not specified. Also path should be in quotes.

Comment: I agree, I always try to specify the full path, just to be safe. +1

Answer (score 0):

Also whenever you need help on connection strings for any database http://www.connectionstrings.com/ is a great reference.