# Run SQL script on MDF file in App_Data

Tags: asp.net, sql, ssms, mdf, app-data

I have the following setup:

- Development: My own computer using an MDF file with a connectionstring which refers to my app_data folder.
- Production: An online server with its own SQL database

When I want to create a new table / fields in my system, I create it in deployment and then run those scripts on production without data.

Now, I am in the opposite situation: I've generated scripts from my production server, and wants to run those towards my local MDF file.

How do I do that? All the answers i've seen so far doesn't help me.

**I've tried the following**:

I've tried to run the whole SQL script in the "Run query" in Visual Studio, but I get a "The Set SQL construct or statement is not supported." error.

I guess I have to open the MDF file somehow in Microsoft SQL Management Studio - but I can't really find a way to get it all to work.

**EDIT**:

After half a year, I've been using the method suggested as the answer again and again. It is by far the best solution. No more MDF files in the project!

I would strongly suggest anyone reading this to start having your databases in your local database.

Comment: That "attach `.mdf` file from disk" approach is really not a good idea. Why aren't you just using your SQL Server instance on your development machine - same as in production? Create the database **on the server instance**, use the logical database name instead of fiddling around with `.mdf` files in the file system - and it makes it **just that much easier** to run scripts against it, back it up etc.

Comment: I guess that's probably the best solution. I will definetely look into that.

Is the other way possible?

Comment: Don't know - I gave up on that "attach .mdf" approach too quickly to ever get to the point where I had to execute a `.sql` script against that file....

Comment: I ended up implementing your solution instead.. Thanks!

Please post an Answer, so anyone searching for this can get that advise easily :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the whole *AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed. Since that `.mdf` file is not attached to your SQL Server instance that's already installed, there's many things you cannot do:

- you cannot use `BACKUP` to back up your database
- you cannot easily execute `.sql` scripts against your database
- and quite a few more things

The only **really viable** solution in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `YourDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Comment: You have to take the **User Instance = true** parameter out of your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to an MDF in Visual Studio:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/173221/188926

You can then open in SQL Server Object Explorer and run queries.