# OLEDB connection to mdf file

Tags: sql, database, oledb, oledbconnection, mdf

I am working on a development project that needs to connect to a sql database. The thing is,is that the database will be stored only on the local machine. I also only have access SQL Server express, and I cannot use a .sdf database because the limit on it is 4Gb. I created the .mdf in visual studio with correct format and layout and placed the files on the development machine. Now, the only way to connect to it (or any database) using the software we have to use is with an OLEDB connection. I tried connecting to it with SQL Express, but it errors out probably because it is not an .sdf file. Does anyone have any ideas? I have been all over the internet and im starting to wonder if it is possible. I can connect to an mdf file in visual studio C#. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Just use an OLEDB connection to the file http://www.connectionstrings.com/access

Comment: that will work for a mdb file, but not an mdf

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173209/how-do-i-connect-to-an-mdf-microsoft-sql-server-database-file-in-a-simple-web) help you?