# Connect .mdf file and read

Tags: c#, .net

I have .mdf file.

- DataBase name - *people*
- .mdf file path - *D:\db\People.mdf*

Next I try connct to mdf

```js
DbProviderFactory df = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient");

using (DbConnection cn = df.CreateConnection()){
  Console.WriteLine("Your connection object is a: {0}", cn.GetType().Name);
  cn.ConnectionString =
    @"Data Source=(local);AttachDbFilename=D:\db\People.mdf;"+
      "Initial Catalog=People;Integrated Security=True";
  cn.Open();
  DbCommand cmd = df.CreateCommand();
  Console.WriteLine("Your command object is a: {0}", cmd.GetType().Name);
  cmd.Connection = cn;
  cmd.CommandText = "Select * From priluki";

  using (DbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
    while (dr.Read())
      Console.WriteLine("-> {0}  {1}",
        dr["first_name"].ToString(), dr["last_name"].ToString());
  }
}
```

And get Error:

> "An unhandled exception of type "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException"
>   in System.Data.dll
>
> For more information: When connecting to SQL Server error occurred
>   with the network or to a specific instance. The server was not found
>   or is not available. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

Comment: Your app can't make a connection to the database. [Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: Are you sure Initial Catalog = is the right syntax?  Try Database=

Comment: tell me, are you sure the mdf file has the right permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to diagnostic your connexion to server 
 [FIX : ERROR : (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 – Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: )](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/)
and
[How do I connect to an .mdf (Microsoft SQL Server Database File) in a simple web project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173209/how-do-i-connect-to-an-mdf-microsoft-sql-server-database-file-in-a-simple-web)