# How can I read a .mdf file generated by Snap Survey software using C#?

Tags: c#, mdf

I have several .mdf files from Snap Survey (v10.0 or lower) but could not open them by SSMS or any .mdf viewer softwares.

Comment: To use `.mdf` files, you must have an instance of **SQL Server** installed where you can attach the `.mdf` to - once you've done that, **then** you can look at the contents of the database in SSMS

Comment: The problem is that the .mdf can't be attached, SSMS says the file is not a primary database file, or corrupted.

Comment: You can never attach a `.mdf` from a newer version of SQL Server to an older instance. Can you find out which **version** of SQL Server that "Snap Survey" software is using to create its `.mdf` files?? Or possibly that file is really corrupted - then you're out of luck, basically

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken a MDF file is a database file. You can connect to it using a SQL Connection. You can read how to do that over here: [How do I connect to an .mdf (Microsoft SQL Server Database File) in a simple web project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173209/how-do-i-connect-to-an-mdf-microsoft-sql-server-database-file-in-a-simple-web/173375#173375)