# Connection String on Visual Studio 2013 with SQL Server 2014

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, connection-string, sql-server-2014, mdf

This is my connection string on my Visual Studio, my database file name is **IOOP_Database**

```
Data Source=IDEA-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=IOOP_Database;Integrated Security=True
```

The problem is when I run this system on another laptop, there will be a error because of the connection string. Is there any way I can state my connection string as **Date Source=IOOP_Database.mdf**? I've also moved my mdf file to my Visual Studio project's debug folder, so the project file and the sql database file are actually together.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500829/sql-express-connection-string-mdf-file-location-relative-to-application-locatio

Comment: You can use ".\" instead of "IDEA-PC\" - the dot stands for the local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AttachDbFilename property in connction strings. It has some limitations and has been advised to use that only in development environment not production.

> AttachDBFilename is unique to SQL Express, it spins up a user instance of SQL Express attached to a specific DB Filename for single user mode.  Database is simply the name of the database to use, it has no additional connotation.  For any production server, you would most likely not be using AttachDBFilename.  It is strictly useful for development and experimentation in single-user mode.
>   [from MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f21c0728-935d-492a-baaf-ff2704e3683b/attachdbfilename-option-in-connection-string?forum=sqldataaccess)

Also you might find these helpful:

- [similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173209/how-do-i-connect-to-an-mdf-microsoft-sql-server-database-file-in-a-simple-web)
- [usage example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.attachdbfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)