# cannot open MSSQL database in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, mysql

I've a local html page that I'm working on. It's mostly HTML and Javascript and some aspx c#.
Whenever I am trying open the database, I get error: 
`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "Database.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'ROYI\user'.`

I searched a bit on the internet, and I've learned that this uses the windows authentication but it doesn't seem to work. I don't have a password for this db, so why can't it connect?

My connection string is:

```cs
"Server= localhost; Database=Database.mdf; Integrated Security = SSPI; ";
```

When I do:

```cs
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
conn.Open();
```

I get the error on `conn.open();`.

Where is the problem with my connection string?

Comment: Is the Database name is "Database.mdf" or you trying to open a connection to a MDF file?

Comment: Might be helpful, Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173209/how-do-i-connect-to-an-mdf-microsoft-sql-server-database-file-in-a-simple-web

Comment: The title says MSSQL database, but then the <mysql> tag is used. Which dbms is actually used?

Comment: @SathishGuru the name is `Database` and the file type is `mdf`.

Comment: @jarlh the database file is of type `mdf`

Comment: @VijayRajendiran I tried this: `Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=c:\asd\qwe\mydbfile.mdf; Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;` but I don't really know what the difference between `mydbfile.mdf` is and  `dbname`.